# Batch - Passing variables into new batch files inside for loop /L

Tags: loops, batch-file, variables, cmd

I have a script that creates new batch files inside a `for` loop.

This is the code:

```bash
@echo on

SET "files=2"
SET "desired_count=2"

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%files%) DO (
    IF %%G LSS 10 (
        (
        echo echo on
        echo set "counter=0"
        echo set desired_count=%desired_count%
        echo.
        echo :startpoint
        echo set /a "counter+=1"
        echo IF "!counter!" LSS %desired_count% goto startpoint
        ) >> file_0%%G.bat
        
    ) 
)
```

I am completely lost when trying to pass variables inside `for` and `if` statements. The solution presented in some other forum posts suggests using `set local EnableDelayedExpansion`, but I have not managed to get that to work for me so far.

In the created .bat files I would like the script to loop until the `desired_count` is met.

The `file_01.bat` that is created is below.

```bash
echo on
set "counter=0"
set desired_count=2

:startpoint
set /a "counter+=1"
IF "!counter!" LSS 2 goto startpoint
```

When that is submitted it infinitely loops around this line:

```bash
IF "!counter!" LSS 2 goto startpoint
```

Playing around with different combinations of `set local EnableDelayedExpansion`, changed what happened, but I couldn't get it correctly count in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo on

SETLOCAL

SET "files=2"
SET "desired_count=2"

FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%files%) DO (
    IF %%G LSS 10 (
        (
        echo echo on

        ECHO SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

        echo set "counter=0"
        echo set desired_count=%desired_count%
        echo.
        echo :startpoint
        echo set /a "counter+=1"
        echo IF !counter! LSS %desired_count% goto startpoint
        ) >> file_0%%G.bat
        
    ) 
)
```

[untested]

Changes : Inserted `setlocal` after `@echo on`. This establishes a `local environment` which means that any changes made to the environment variables while running this code are discarded when the batch ends so the environment remains clean - not altered by successively running batch files.

Inserted `ECHO SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` to follow the `echo on` in the generated file. The full command is `SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, but by default, `ENABLEEXTENSIONS` is enabled and `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` disabled, so this shorter form is usually adequate. This instruction causes `cmd` to interpret `!var!` as the **run-time** value of `var` (ie. as it might change within a loop.)

Removed quotes from `IF "!counter!" LS…` As your original code would be interpreted, the statement would be resolved to "if `"!counter!"` LSS `2` …" where `"!counter!"` is precisely that - the literal string `"!counter!"`. Since `"!counter!"` is less than `2`, you get an infinite loop.

The `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` would change this interpretation to "if `"thecurrentvalueofcounter"` LSS `2` …" - but this is still incorrect as `if` syntax compares the expressions on both sides of the comparator (`LSS`) literally, so you might get "if `"2"` LSS `2` …" for instance. The string `"2"` is always less than `2`. To accomplish what you need to do, you need to compare the two values, ie `!counter!` LSS `2`.

Note that `IF "!counter!" LSS "2" g…` may *appear* to work, but in this case, the comparison is performed as *strings*, hence `"2" LSS "2"`,`"3" LSS "2"`, etc. Perfect... except `"12" LSS "2"` is **true** because the comparison is performed character-by-character and `1` *is* less than `2`.

However ------

In the generated batch, you don't need to use the `delayedexpansion` syntax as `counter` is not contained in a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of commands)

Hence, you could use

```
    echo IF %%counter%% LSS %desired_count% goto startpoint
```

which would generate

```
IF %counter% LSS 2 goto startpoint
```

- as `%` "escapes" (turns off) the special meaning of `%`, and since the generated `IF %counter%…` code is not in a code block, there is no need for the `delayedexpansion` syntax here. This means that the `delayedexpansion` keyword is also not required.

See [Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947) for more info

Comment: The explanation on why the code wasn't working has helped massively and changing to %%counter%% has resolved the problem. Thanks again for your help.